# How to create a dynamic filter with multiple check boxes in angular 4 or more?

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to filter my data with multiple checkboxes.
My code is below.

I'm following the example that I found:
https://codepen.io/magalhaespaulo/pen/jbYXPP

So far, I have managed to obtain the data filtering by the categories:

Component.html:

```
<menu class="box" *ngFor="let cats of categories">
    <h2>{{cats}}</h2>
    <div *ngFor="let value of getItems(cats,products)">
<input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="searchString"click)="filters(cats,value)" ng-model="value">
{{value}}
    </div>
</menu>

<article class="box">
    <h2>products</h2>
     <div *ngFor="let item of products ">
{{item.name}} ~ {{item.color}} ~ {{item.size}} ~ {{item.price}} ~ {{item.gener}}
     </div>
</article>
```

Component.ts:

```
products = [
{ name: 'Heathered flannel buffalo plaid shirt',
 color: 'red', size: 'small', price:49.95, gener: 'female' },
{ name: 'Flannel plaid shirt',
 color: 'yellow', size: 'medium', price:49.95, gener: 'male' },
{ name: 'Heathered oxford shirt (slim fit)',
 color: 'blue', size: 'large', price:49.95,  gener: 'male' },
{ name: 'Classic plaid oxford',
 color: 'green', size: 'small', price:49.95,  gener: 'male' },
{ name: 'Lived-in chambray shirt',
 color: 'purple', size: 'medium', price:39.95,  gener: 'male' }
]

 //With this code I obtain data according to a category:

getItems(value, array) {
return (array || []).map(function (w) {
  return w[value];
}).filter(function (w, idx, arr) {
  if (typeof w === 'undefined') {
    return false;
  }
  return arr.indexOf(w) === idx;
});
}
```

The result which I want is like the typical filter that we se on ecommerce pages. In this case, I've got a list of products that contains: color, size, price and gender.

What is missing, is to filter the products when clicking on a category, but I have no idea how to do it.

In the examples I found used pipe but can not be applied to several options at once, only to a specific option (color or size or gender or price), but I want to apply the filter using one or more options.

I hope you help me.